# How to make a ListActivity with custom List Item with nested clickable Button

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, listadapter

now i have a activity, that shows a list of usernames. OK it works. But that i need is to show a custom listview item with the username at the left and a button at the right (this button will do a call to a programatically given phone number).

I know that i have to do a custom adapter, but my skills are too low. And also i dont know how to use it when i have done.

Can someone help me making a easy custom adapter to manage my listitem with one textview and one button and giving me the code to use that custom adapter?

the adapter should be able to use this new list_item2.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/friendName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/callButton"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/friendName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Call"
        android:width="100px"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the code that i use now:

list_item.xml:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

this is the listactivity class:

```
public class AllActivity extends ListActivity {

    RemoteConnection con; //conexion remota
    //private MyDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    private List<Friend> friends; //lista de amigos
    private List<String> usernames; //lista de usernames de amigos, para rellenar el listview
    //private List<Permission> permissions;

    //para almacenar la config local de mi app, mostrarme o no en el mapa...
    static SharedPreferences settings;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor configEditor;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        settings=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
        configEditor = settings.edit();

        friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
        usernames = new ArrayList<String>();

        //mDbHelper=MyApplication.getDatabaseAdapter();
        con = new RemoteConnection();

        actualizar();

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == 1) {
            setResult(1);
            finish();                   
        }
    }
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        actualizar();       
   }

    public void actualizar()
    {
        //friends = con.RetrieveFriends(settings.getString("login",""));
        friends = MyApplication.getDatabaseAdapter().retrieveAllFriends();
        usernames.clear();

        for (int i=0;i<friends.size();i++)
        //for (int i=0;i<permissions.size();i++)
        {
            usernames.add(i,friends.get(i).getFullName());
            //if (friends.get(i).getLastPosition()!=null)
            //  usernames.add(i,friends.get(i).getLastPosition().getpositiontimeFormated());    
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item3, usernames));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {


              Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //bundle is like the letter
              bundle.putString ("user", friends.get(position).getFullName()); //arg1 is the keyword of the txt, arg2 is the txt
              bundle.putString ("email", friends.get(position).getEmail());
              bundle.putString ("permission", friends.get(position).getPermission());

              Intent i=null;
              if (friends.get(position).getPermission().equals("total"))
                  i = new Intent (AllActivity.this, Locate.class);
              else if (friends.get(position).getPermission().equals("perhours"))
                  i = new Intent (AllActivity.this, LocatePerHours.class);
              else
                  i = new Intent (AllActivity.this, LocatePerDays.class);

              i.putExtras(bundle);
              startActivity(i);
              //startActivityForResult(i, 0);
          }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i edited my code to be compatible with yours

i write your code with modification to achieve what you want... i call InitialActivity  yo yhe ListActivity and populate the list from a string array (populate them is not your problem) so, maybe the other things will help you...

```
package com.franco.test2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InitialActivity extends ListActivity {


//  private List<Friend> friends; //lista de amigos
    private ArrayList<String> usernames; //lista de usernames de amigos, para rellenar el listview
    private String[] usernames_array;
    private ActivityList listAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        usernames_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.usernames);

        actualizar();

    }

    public void actualizar()
    {
        //friends = con.RetrieveFriends(settings.getString("login",""));
//        friends = MyApplication.getDatabaseAdapter().retrieveAllFriends();
//        usernames.clear();

//        for (int i=0;i<usernames.size();i++)
        //for (int i=0;i<permissions.size();i++)
//        {
//            usernames.add(i,friends.get(i).getFullName());
            //if (friends.get(i).getLastPosition()!=null)
            //  usernames.add(i,friends.get(i).getLastPosition().getpositiontimeFormated());    
//        }

        usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < usernames_array.length ; i++){
            usernames.add(usernames_array[i]);
        }
        listAdapter = new ActivityList(InitialActivity.this, android.R.id.text1, usernames);


//        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item3, usernames));
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {



              //startActivityForResult(i, 0);
          }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //bundle is like the letter
         bundle.putString ("user", listAdapter.getItem(position)); //arg1 is the keyword of the txt, arg2 is the txt
//         bundle.putString ("user", friends.get(position).getFullName()); //arg1 is the keyword of the txt, arg2 is the txt
//         bundle.putString ("email", friends.get(position).getEmail());
//         bundle.putString ("permission", friends.get(position).getPermission());

//         Intent i=null;
//         if (friends.get(position).getPermission().equals("total"))
//             i = new Intent (AllActivity.this, Locate.class);
//         else if (friends.get(position).getPermission().equals("perhours"))
//             i = new Intent (AllActivity.this, LocatePerHours.class);
//         else
//             i = new Intent (AllActivity.this, LocatePerDays.class);
//
//         i.putExtras(bundle);
//         startActivity(i);
    }

    private OnClickListener callBtnListener = new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Info","Username: " + v.getTag());
        }};

    class ActivityList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public ActivityList(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(InitialActivity.this);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_item2, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendName);
                holder.button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.callButton);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.text.setText(getItem(position));
            holder.button.setOnClickListener(callBtnListener);
            holder.button.setTag( getItem(position) );
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView text;
        Button button;
    }

}
```

i also deleted the last line (onClick) and add an onClickListener on the list activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/friendName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/callButton"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/friendName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Call"
            android:width="100px"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

i tested in my device and works, i delete the DataHolder class.

The other things like the Bundle map, Intent, is commented because i think is not your problem.

cheers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur time, im trying to compile your code.... what is android.R.id.text1 on the line: listAdapter = new ActivityList(InitialActivity.this, android.R.id.text1, usernames);
 ???????

Comment: oh, sorry, i forget about that, is a default parameter for the ArrayAdapter constructor, it's needed to instantiate the array adapter (in this textview are placed the ListAdapter item objects.toString() on instantiation time i.e. ), however, when you construct the view for each item in the list, you can use the textview obtained from the inflated view to place the data. Like holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendName);

Comment: i tryed changuing the line with: listAdapter = new ActivityList(AllActivity.this, R.id.friendName, usernames);

Comment: but i still get an error.... it have problems with the third parameter, it needs a ArrayList<dataholder> but i am using List<String>...... how to solve that?

Comment: can you change the code to not use DataHolder??? it is not compatible with my code

Comment: ALSO I GOT AN ERROR ON THE XML FILE:  error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'onClick' in package 'android' list_item3.xml /GPSLoc/res/layout

Comment: hi!, i edited my code above, let me know if there is a problem